# Python dictionary with multiple keys pointing to same list in memory efficient way

Tags: python

I have this unique requirement which can be explained by this code.
This is working code but not memory efficient.

```
data = [[
        "A 5408599",
        "B 8126880",
        "A 2003529",
    ],
    [
        "C 9925336",
        "C 3705674",
        "A 823678571",
        "C 3205170186",
    ],
    [
        "C 9772980",
        "B 8960327",
        "C 4185139021",
        "D 1226285245",
        "C 2523866271",
        "D 2940954504",
        "D 5083193",
    ]]

temp_dict = {
    item: index for index, sublist in enumerate(data)
        for item in sublist
}

print(data[temp_dict["A 2003529"]])

out: ['A 5408599', 'B 8126880', 'A 2003529']
```

In short, I want each item of sub-list to be indexable and should return the sublist.

The above method works but It takes a lot of memory when data is large. Is there any better, memory and CPU friendly way? The data is stored as a JSON file.

**Edit**
I tried the answers for the largest possible use case scenario (1000 sublist, 100 items in each sublist, 1 million queries) and here are results (mean of 10 runs):

```
Method,    Time (seconds),    Extra Memory used
my,        0.637              40 Mb
deceze,    0.63               40 Mb
James,     0.78               200 kb
Pant,      > 300              0 kb
mcsoini,   forever            0 kb
```

Comment: `{item: sublist for sublist in data for item in sublist}` might be slightly more efficient and direct…?!

Comment: Yes. for my sample case. In my real case scenario, the sublist is having 100s of items and thousands of such sublists. user of the code is having small memory (< 2gb) so when other heavy app is running, they ae complaining that your script is slow.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? Perhaps a hybrid approach would work, in which you index by the first letter, and then iterate through a few candidate lists to find your exact value, sort of like a hash table collision resolution algorithm.

Comment: For efficient way use generators like yield().

Comment: Thanks. I will learn what "hash table collision resolution" means.

Comment: There is no big difference between both methods : the Rahul's stores a ref to an int, the deceze's a ref to a list. The result in memory size is the same ; the cost of the comprehension is the same ; the benefit is a direct access to sublist.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: I didn't knew that. It means after that my `data` and `temp_dict` will share same sub-list. No copy will be done?

Comment: @deceze: your hybrid approach will be faster at start, but slower at use. The dict is already a hash table.

Comment: @Edouard Yes, it's all about a space-time tradeoff.

Comment: @Rahul: no copy at all; you can check with `id()` and will see same addresses.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will check this for my larger sample.

Comment: you say that you take `data` from a `json` file - would another structure than the list of lists you have now be an option? I mean, create sth else on import? right now, you extend memory demand as you create the `temp_dict` from `data` - maybe the problem could be mitigated by creating only one structure in the first place?

Comment: creating only one structure may lead to more disk space but yes memory can be saved. Thanks. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really in a trade-off space between the time/memory it takes to generate the dictionary versus the time it takes to scan the entire data for an on-the-fly method.

If you want a low memory method, you can use a function that searches each sublist for the value.  Using a generator will get initial results faster to the user, but for large data sets, this will be slow between returns.

```py
data = [[
        "A 5408599",
        "B 8126880",
        "A 2003529",
    ],
    [
        "C 9925336",
        "C 3705674",
        "A 823678571",
        "C 3205170186",
    ],
    [
        "C 9772980",
        "B 8960327",
        "C 4185139021",
        "D 1226285245",
        "C 2523866271",
        "D 2940954504",
        "D 5083193",
    ]]


def find_list_by_value(v, data):
    for sublist in data:
        if v in sublist:
            yield sublist

for s in find_list_by_value("C 9772980", data):
    print(s)
```

As mentioned in the comments, building a hash table based just on the first letter or first 2 or 3 character might be a good place to start.  This will allow you to build a candidate list of sublists, then scan those to see if the value is in the sublist.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_key(v, size=3):
    return v[:size]

def get_keys(sublist, size=3):
    return set(get_key(v, size) for v in sublist)

def find_list_by_hash(v, data, hash_table, size=3):
    key = get_key(v, size)
    candidate_indices = hash_table.get(key, set())
    for ix in candidates:
        if v in data[ix]:
            yield data[ix]

# generate the small hash table
quick_hash = defaultdict(set)
for i, sublist in enumerate(data):
    for k in get_keys(sublist, 3):
        quick_hash[k].add(i)

# lookup a value by the small hash
for s in find_list_by_hash("C 9772980", data, quick_hash, 3):
    print(s)
```

In this code `quick_hash` will take some time to build, because you are scanning your entire data structure.  However, the memory foot print will be much smaller.  You main parameter for tuning performance is `size`.  Smaller size will have a smaller memory footprint, but will take longer when running `find_list_by_hash` because your candidate pool will be larger.  You can do some testing to see what the right `size` should be for your data.   Just be mindful that all of your values are at **least** as long as `size`.

Comment: And I thought that I know python and programming. Thanks. There's a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
list(filter(lambda x: any(["C 9772980" in x]),data))
```

No need to make a mapping structure.

Comment: Thank you, Man. I will have to check if this is faster.

Comment: it will be much faster at start because there is no comprehension to compute, but way much slower at use because for each element to find, this method will re-scan the whole data.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: I also feel the same. My actual use is have more of the use cases than the start cases.

Comment: @EdouardThiel true. But I am not sure about the exact use case.

Comment: It's actually simple. I have a list containing 10000 sub-list which contains 100 items. I need to query for any item from the above list to get the sub-list and process. I also need to merge the sublist if any common member is that but only once in a while. main use is querying it like database. I can not use databases like sqlite, sql-server-local-db. as I don't know how to use it as of know. I will learn if DB will be useful here.

Comment: Got it. If you can maintain a structure somewhere then you do use DB and call it everytime you need to search for any element. If you can't then this will be much faster than making a dict everytime.

Comment: @BhushanPant: Dictionary will be created only once during runtime. not every time.

Comment: Sure, then using dictionary will be faster for searching.

Answer (score 2):

try this, using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
rows = df.shape[0]
for row in range(rows):
    print[[row]]    #Do something with your data
```

this looks simple solution, even if your data grows big, this will handle that efficiently

Comment: check the size of your `df`: it is considerably larger than the list `data` (>x12) and the dict `temp_dict` (~x2) for the given example data - not exactly memory-efficient I'd say

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't think this argument is valid, since pandas does not physically copy the strings in this case

Comment: @mcsoini, I admit my comment is a bit superficial - a more detailled analysis would be necessary to determine if `pandas` handles this problem more efficient than built-in python functionality.

Comment: @MrFuppes: I agree. Why to use `pandas` if it can be done using `stdlib`. Just because it's look fancy?

Comment: @Rahul: Pandas solutions are extremely fast to implement and efficient under the hood, so why not try, even if there's no guarantee they offer superior performance?

Comment: But you did not provide how I will query the dataframe. Can you show me how your solution will solve my problem. I tried @mcsoini's solution for pandas but it is taking forever for 1 million queries. I don't know why. Please see my updated question for results of various methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how this would behave for larger amounts data, but you could try something along the lines of:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.loc[:, (df == 'A 2003529').any(axis=0)]
Out[39]: 
           0
0  A 5408599
1  B 8126880
2  A 2003529
3       None
4       None
5       None
6       None
```

Edit: Does not seem to be beneficial in terms of time, based on a quick test with some fake larger scale data.